# Inner product of a vector with itself vs inner product of a vector with its permutation

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_{i}||x_{\pi(i)}|,
\end{align*}
where $\pi:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a permutation. Intuitively, it makes sense, but I haven't been able to show it or find a good reference.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_{i}||x_{\pi(i)}|\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{\frac12} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{\pi(i)}^2\right)^{\frac12}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Oh, that's immediate as the $\ell_2$-norm is invariant under permutations! Thanks a lot for your help!!